# What is the source of this from Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

What is the source of this from Star Wars?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it's from Star Wars?

Comment: Definitely looks like a throne Palpatine would use but its not from any of the movies. Possible concept art.

Comment: Who became what, what are you saying? I've searched with TinEye, and no hits. Looks like concept art as knightwatch suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Snoke’s throne  Designs
concept by artist Christopher Rosewarne

[image]

[image]

[image]